# mutating with ifelse() when condition requires that any of the group member satisfy it

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `dplyr` functions to create a new value based on another variable, if the group contains a variable that meets my condition.

Now since I tried but couldn't get the above to sound clearer, a short example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3), var = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), gender = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here, I want to create a new variable (newvar) where

1. if a group (`id`) contains any female member ("F"), `newvar` should just have the same value as `var`
2. if a group only contains male members, `newvar` should have value 1

My expected result:

```
# id var gender newvar
#  1   1     M       1 
#  1   2     M       1
#  1   3     M       1
#  2   4     M       4
#  2   5     M       5
#  2   6     F       6
#  3   7     F       7
#  3   8     M       8
```

My attempt :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(newvar = ifelse(any(gender == "F"), var, 1))
```

My result :

```
# id var gender newvar
#  1   1     M       1 
#  1   2     M       1
#  1   3     M       1
#  2   4     M       4
#  2   5     M       4
#  2   6     F       4
#  3   7     F       7
#  3   8     M       7
```

This happens every time when I use `group_by` and `mutate` together, where `ifelse` function has a condition that uses `any` function & either the TRUE or the FALSE result resorts on another column -- so in words, when I tell the code to 'create a column that has values that depend on the group, where if any of the group members satisfy a condition let it have the value that depend on another (3rd) column, but if none of the members satisfy that condition let it have some other value'

I would appreciate it if I can learn (1) why my attempt fails and (2) what would be the better / best version of writing the code that would bring the desired result.

(PS I know the title and the first paragraph sucks but couldn't get it to sound better..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your version doesn't provide the expected output is because `any(gender == "F")` evaluates to a length one logical vector. Thus, the value for that group will be length one and repeated to fill the group.

Here's an approach with `map_dbl` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(newvar = map_dbl(var, ~if_else(any(gender == "F"), .x, 1)))
## A tibble: 8 x 4
## Groups:   id [3]
#     id   var gender newvar
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1     1     1 M           1
#2     1     2 M           1
#3     1     3 M           1
#4     2     4 M           4
#5     2     5 M           5
#6     2     6 F           6
#7     3     7 F           7
#8     3     8 M           8
```

An alternative approach is to repeat the logical vector produced by `any` to be the length of `var`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(newvar = if_else(rep(any(gender == "F"),n()), var, 1))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id   var gender newvar
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1     1     1 M           1
#2     1     2 M           1
#3     1     3 M           1
#4     2     4 M           4
#5     2     5 M           5
#6     2     6 F           6
#7     3     7 F           7
#8     3     8 M           8
```

Comment: Wow thank you! That's very clear. I'd expected something like your second method from my code but what you explained makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

As already explained by Ian that the `test` condition is of length one hence output from `ifelse` is also of length 1 which repeats for entire column.

Here you can make use `if`/`else` instead of `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(newvar = if(any(gender == "F")) var else 1)

#     id   var gender newvar
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1     1     1 M           1
#2     1     2 M           1
#3     1     3 M           1
#4     2     4 M           4
#5     2     5 M           5
#6     2     6 F           6
#7     3     7 F           7
#8     3     8 M           8
```